# JSON.NET Argument Exception when creating JSON with LINQ

Tags: linq, json.net

I'm using JSON.NET Linq to JSON, when I execute the below I get the following argument exception:

> Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

What's wrong with the code

```
string content = new JObject(
            new JObject("auth",
                        new JProperty("user", "anemail@gmail.com"),
                        new JProperty("secret", "somepassword")
                ),
            new JObject("config",
                        new JProperty("template", "1")
                ),
            new JObject("data",
                        new JProperty("email", "body")
                )
            ).ToString();
```

Comment: Tim is right. What you wrote looks more like the creation of an XML structure using `XDocument` and `XElement` where you can mix the node name and its child nodes in the parameter list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the JSON.NET [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm), you need to wrap your JObjects in JProperties themselves:

```
string content = new JObject(
                   new JProperty("auth",
                     new JObject(
                       new JProperty("user", "anemail@gmail.com"),
                       new JProperty("secret", "somepassword")
                     )
                   ),
                   new JProperty("config",
                     new JObject(
                       new JProperty("template", "1")
                     )
                   ),
                   new JProperty("data",
                     new JObject(
                       new JProperty("email", "body")
                     )
                   )
                 ).ToString();
```